# How to extract specific values from imported csv and write it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

I have a csv in the below format:

```
number,values
686790635,{'2019-05-24T13:46:35': 'CSCvp87661'}
686235835,{'2019-02-27T14:13:53': 'CSCvj48931'}
689324672,{'2020-06-19T08:50:53': 'CSCvs42803'}
689995407,{'2020-09-27T05:51:39': 'CSCvg55782'}
688751767,{'2020-03-26T11:28:44': 'CSCvc81396'}
689868626,"{'2020-09-10T01:29:51': 'CSCux76799', '2020-09-10T01:29:53': 'CSCux76799'}"
689206940,{'2020-06-02T20:40:44': 'CSCvo65492'}
686259208,"{'2019-03-11T02:55:43': 'CSCvi66732', '2019-03-11T02:55:52': 'CSCvg81628'}"
689030956,{'2020-05-07T10:05:09': 'CSCvh19223'}
```

Here I was trying to extract the values as in below list:

```
values = [CSCvp87661,CSCvj48931, CSCvs42803, CSCvg55782, CSCvc81396, CSCux76799, CSCux76799, CSCvo65492, CSCvi66732, CSCvg81628, CSCvh19223]
```

I was trying to loop over and iterate the values but not able to get it in the exact list format.
Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Please include your current code and the discrepancy of current and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - these is odd csv format. There are better options to structure these data - e.g. JSON

```
import csv
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import chain
with open('data.csv') as f:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = list(chain(*(literal_eval(line['values']).values() for line in rdr)))
print(data)
```

output

```
['CSCvp87661', 'CSCvj48931', 'CSCvs42803', 'CSCvg55782', 'CSCvc81396', 'CSCux76799', 'CSCux76799', 'CSCvo65492', 'CSCvi66732', 'CSCvg81628', 'CSCvh19223']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `values` column is a JSON dictionary, so you can use the `json` built-in module to convert it to a python dictionary, and `.values()` to get the values, here is some simple (untested) code to help you, you may need to use `.strip('"')` to remove the extra quotes on some lines:

```
import csv
import json

values = []

with open('your_csv_file.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        value = row['values']
        
        # Parse the JSON string
        value_dict = json.loads(value)
        
        value_list = list(value_dict.values())
        
        values.extend(value_list)

print(values)
```

Comment: these are not valied JSON, because of the single quotes

Comment: @buran true, so `.replace("'", '"')` should be used before

Comment: I would use `ast.literal_eval` - see my answer.